# NullPointerException when storing lines in an arraylist

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm getting a NullPointerException in java (at this line :FileReader fstream = new FileReader(fileName)) when I try to read a text file line by line and store them in an arraylist with this code :

```
public ArrayList<String> StoreLineByLine(String fileName) throws IOException {
    String str;

    ArrayList<String> Line = new ArrayList<String>();
    FileReader fstream = new FileReader(fileName);
    BufferedReader myFileReader = new BufferedReader(fstream);

    while ((str = myFileReader.readLine()) != null) {
        Line.add(str);
    }
    myFileReader.close();
    return Line;
}
```

Could anyone help me understand the problem ?
Thanks a lot !

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217449/how-can-i-debug-this-nullpointer-exception) and [this](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx)

Comment: Please add an error log and tell us which line exactly throws the nullPointerException.

Comment: Try researching like I did, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: Works perfectly for me, tried it on my system, calling `StoreLineByLine(String fileName)` from `main()` . Check your `fileName`.

Comment: Tested on OS X. If `fileName` is NULL, it yields a NPE on that line. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're getting a NPE on that line, then `fileName` must be null.

BTW, if you're using JDK 8 then this may be a better way to load the lines. Replace the contents of your method with this:

```
return Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileName), Charset.defaultCharset());
```

...and change the method's return type from `ArrayList<String>` to `List<String>`.

Comment: Hello, it's the first time I use this website so I don't know how to log the error. The error is on that line :  fstream = new FileReader(fileName);
I don't understand how come it is null!

Comment: Well it still doesn't work :/

Comment: whats new issue you are getting?

Comment: I still get the NPE error on that line

Comment: @user3767791 never pass fileName as null ... have a null check first in the method

Comment: @user3767791: That's because the method is being called with a null value for `fileName`. If you're running from an IDE, then likely the command line arguments are not being supplied to your `main` method.

Comment: Yes I had a problem with the opening, it's all good now !